# Dynamic Pages with Dreamweaver access to CSS

Tags: php, css, dreamweaver

I have a php site setup on a testing server. I created a master page that is to dynamically include different content pages. The master page has all the head information such as the style sheet link. I works just fine in live view. The question I have is if I want to format something in the content page, dreamweaver does not list the classes from the master page. Example I have an index.php and it changes out the body with content pages, like article.php, login.php etc. However if I am editing the content of article.php Dreamweaver does not list the classes form the index.php.

Comment: That was cryptic. Without code, I don't know where to begin! Might I suggest you familiarise yourself with the [Chrome Inspector](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this depending on how recent your version of Dreamweaver is. The first way is using the related files functionality: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSb16ef6880e13ce361172e08122a970c26b-8000.html. In particular, pay attention to the final section "Dynamically-Related Files and Live View Navigation integration".

The other way would be to use the design time style sheets: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7e17a.html

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is not a super-genius or mind-reader. To Dreamweaver, your article.php page is just a page. It has no idea that it's intended to be included into index.php or that it should be looking at the CSS in index.php to look up classes. For all it knows, it *could* be included in index.php, index2.php, or any other file you might have in your structure. So, you'll either have to just remember what CSS classes you've defined and how to use them, or you'll have to find an alternate way of coding the files.

One way I've always used is designing the actual page layout, etc in a static HTML page. Basically just start with the outline of your website, and for each different page of your site, change out what's inside it, tweak it, etc until you get it looking how you want, then move it over to the actual PHP file when it's all ready.

Comment: This is all incorrect. When I open the index.php, Dreamweaver knows all the associated files. I can even display a live view of the php

Comment: Perhaps you misread. If you're in index.php, Dreamweaver can easily detect everything that files links to. However, if you're editing a file which gets included *into* that file, it doesn't have that link. The answer above appears to show how you can explicitly set that link. I'm only explaining the assumption that just because something gets included into one file doesn't mean that's the *only* file it might get included into.